# Type Error appears while opening file in python 3 " expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list" at txt = open(filename)

Tags: python, string, file, typeerror, argv

```
from sys import argv
filename = argv

txt = open(filename) #Error at this line

print("Here's your file {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

Comment: `argv` is a list. What would it mean to `open` a list? What are you actually trying to open?

Comment: Actually, i want to open a file and redirect its read mode to a new variable and then print it on the terminal

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't make sense to open a list anyway. Please read [the docs about `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: "Actually, i want to open a file" Okay. What is the rule that tells you what the name of the file is? Could you show an example of something that the user would type on the command line, and the corresponding file name?

Comment: Did you try checking *what `argv` contains* when you run the program in the desired way? For example, by `print(argv)`?

Answer (score 0):

if you print filename you notice that it's bracketed, meaning it's a list!
Try `print(type(filename))` and you'll see! the open function does not accept list-objects as an argument

Try this

```
filename = argv
filename = str(filename[0]) #converting the list to a string
f = open(filename)
```